# docker not opening ports on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

I have tested a build on 3 different OS X machines and 1 Ubuntu. The ports are configured correctly and I verified using docker ps & docker inspect yet it looks like docker isn't opening the ports in OS X because netstat doesn't list the docker ports

```
 netstat -an | grep 'LISTEN'
```

Our devs use OS X, I was fortunate that one of the devops has an Ubuntu machine. I don't have any funky proxy settings blocking it.

Comment: This question is off-topic for SO as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @The Blue Dog I disagree. Sure, it isn't a programming bug per se but it is part of the process. To build these environments it is using the "programming language" of docker, this is a direct result of that. Being that there are a good number of devs on OSX I think this would be useful so they won't have to waste hours like I did. So, technically you are correct but this is related. I'm writing "code" to build these environments.

Answer (score 2):

Aha. The reason it worked in Ubuntu is that docker isn't run via boot2docker. I was able to fix it (in OS X) by adding port mappings in virtualbox but that's not what I want to do.

Another way is to use the boot2docker ip & port. So for me to access elasticsearch I use 192.168.59.103:9200 ($DOCKER_HOST) to get around the missing mappings. I think it would be nice if the boot2docker installation mapped the ports specified in the EXPOSE statements so that localhost can be used consistently...but I still love docker :-)