# docker not listening on port on OSX - colima

Tags: docker, macos, colima

When trying to map a port with Docker on colima, the map works, but the port is not open for listening on MacOS

You may end here if you went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26343178/1736679) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25331485/1736679) other questions and still stuck.

For:

- OSX
- Using colima
- on M1

A docker container exposing a port **will not be listening** (checked for example with `netstat`) even if `docker port \<container\>` shows it is.

Example docker run: `docker run -p 80:80 -name mycontainer myimage`

What is the solution so that the port is listening in the local host?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer is in the Colima FAQ - [Enable reachable IP address](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#enable-reachable-ip-address)

`colima start --network-address`

It is only a mechanism for OSX because it asks for an admin pwd to be able to work.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! I had forgotten that I was using colima and my container ports were just getting forwarded on the localhost!

Spent countless minutes before coming across this question and answer!

Answer (score 2):

This problem suddenly happened to me, which was odd cause I'd been running docker containers and accessing them via localhost:port.

I tried a bunch of things but stopping and starting colima is what finally did it for me.